# Exercise environment to stretch over following page: doesn't work as expected

Tags: environments, page-breaking

I would like the exercise environment to stretch over following page, this is what I'm getting as shown the picture at bottom:

1. The blue ebox environment doesn't apply to the continuance
   environment;
2. When I insert \begin{continuance} it insert first the
   title "Exercice" with increasing the exercise number, what I don't want, as the exercise number in the continuance environment must be the same than the beginning exercise number. So if the
   beginning exercise number is 0.1, the continued section will be in exercise 0.2; that is how it works actually, yet it should still be in exercise 0.1.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=20cm, paperheight=29cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{qtree}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,arrows,chains,automata,shapes,matrix,positioning,scopes,calc,babel}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.9}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\colorbox{light-gray}{\texttt{#1}}}
\newcommand{\phase}[1]{\par\medskip\textbf{#1}\par\nopagebreak}

\RequirePackage[framemethod=default]{mdframed} % Required for creating the theorem, definition, exercise and corollary boxes

\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{70,50,212} % Define the orange color used for highlighting throughout the book

\newmdenv[skipabove=7pt,
skipbelow=7pt,
rightline=false,
leftline=true,
topline=false,
bottomline=false,
backgroundcolor=ocre!10,
linecolor=ocre,
innerleftmargin=5pt,
innerrightmargin=5pt,
innertopmargin=5pt,
innerbottommargin=5pt,
leftmargin=0cm,
rightmargin=0cm,
linewidth=4pt]{eBox}

\renewcommand{\qedsymbol}{$\blacksquare$}

\newtheorem{exerciceT}{Exercice}[chapter]
\newtheorem*{continuancex}{Suite de l'exercice \continuanceref}

\newenvironment{exercice}
{
\par
    \begin{eBox}\begin{exerciceT}
        \hfill{\color{ocre}\tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}}
}
{
        \par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent\ignorespaces
    \end{exerciceT}\end{eBox}
}

\newenvironment{continuance}[1]
  {\newcommand\continuanceref{\ref{#1}}\exerciceT\continuancex}
  {\endcontinuancex}

\newenvironment{exemple}
{
\par
    \begin{exempleT}
        \par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent
        \tiny\ensuremath{\blacksquare}
        \par\vspace{\baselineskip}\noindent\ignorespaces
    \end{exempleT}
}

\begin{document}
            \begin{exercice}\label{exercice:deterministeVersNonDeterministe}
                Transformez l'automate non déterministe \code{A = (Q,$\Sigma,\delta$,s,F)} de la figure~\ref{exemple:afnd} en un automate fini déterministe \code{A' = (Q',$\Sigma',\delta'$,s',F')}.

                \paragraph{Construction de l'automate fini déterministe \code{A'} par étapes:}

                \begin{enumerate}
                    \item Si \code{Q} $= \{1, 2, 3\}$ est l'ensemble des états de l'automate \code{A} alors:
                        \begin{description}
                            \item \code{Q'} est l'ensemble des sous ensembles de \code{Q}.
                            \item \code{Q'} $= \{\varnothing, \{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{2,3\}, \{1,2,3\} \}$.
                        \end{description}
                    \item $\Sigma$ ne change pas. Donc $\Sigma' = \Sigma$.
                    \item Si $\delta$ est la fonction de transition de \code{A}, alors $\delta'$ est la fonction de transition de \code{A'}. $\delta'$ est la fonction de transition suivante, et est un sous ensemble de \code{Q'} $\times \Sigma \times$ \code{Q'}:

                        \begin{center}
                        \hfill
                          $\!\begin{aligned}[t]
                             \delta = \{\\
                            & \delta(\varnothing, a)=\varnothing\\          
                            & \delta(\{1\}, a)=\varnothing\\
                            & \delta(\{2\}, a)=\varnothing\\
                            & \delta(\{3\}, a)=\{1,2\}\\
                            & \delta(\{1,2\}, a)=\varnothing\\
                            & \delta(\{1,3\},a)=\{1,2\}\\
                            & \delta(\{2,3\},a)=\{1,2\}\\
                            & \delta(\{1,2,3\}, a)=\{1,2\}\\
                          \end{aligned}$\hfill\hfill
                          $\!\begin{aligned}[t]
                            & \\
                            & \delta(\{\varnothing,b\})=\varnothing\\
                            & \delta(\{1\},b)=\{2,3\}\\
                            & \delta(\{2\},b)=\varnothing\\
                            & \delta(\{3\},b)=\varnothing\\
                            & \delta(\{1,2\},b)=\{2,3\}\\
                            & \delta(\{1,3\},b)=\{2,3\}\\
                            & \delta(\{2,3\},b)=\varnothing\\
                            & \delta(\{1,2,3\},b)=\{2,3\}\}\\
                          \end{aligned}$\hfill
                        \end{center}

                    \item \code{s} ne change pas. \code{s} étant l'état initial de \code{A}, il demeure l'état initial de \code{A'}. Si \code{s'} est l'état initial de \code{A'}, alors \code{s' = s = 1}.
                    \item \code{F} étant l'ensemble des états finaux de \code{A} alors \code{F'} est l'ensemble des états finaux de \code{A'}.
                        Les états finaux du nouvel automate \code{A'} sont tous des sous ensembles des états contenant l'état $3$.

                        Donc \code{F'} $= \{\{3\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}$
                \end{enumerate}
            \end{exercice}
            \begin{continuance}{exercice:deterministeVersNonDeterministe}
                D'où le diagramme des transitions suivant:
                \begin{center}
                    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth, shorten >=1pt, auto, node distance=2.5cm, initial text = Début]
                        \node[initial, state](4){$1$};
                        \node[state](1)[above left=of 4]{$2$};
                        \node[state](2)[right=of 1]{$\varnothing$};
                        \node[state, accepting](3)[right=of 2]{$3$};
                        \node[state, accepting](5)[right=of 4]{${\{2, 3\}}$};
                        \node[state](6)[right of=5]{${\{1, 2\}}$};
                        \node[state, accepting](7)[below=of 5]{${\{1, 3\}}$};
                        \node[state, accepting](8)[below=of 6]{${\{1, 2, 3\}}$};

                        \path[->] (1) edge node {a}   (2);
                        \path[->] (1) edge [swap] node {b}   (2);

                        \path[->] (2) edge [loop above] node {a, b}   (2);

                        \path[->] (3) edge node {b}   (2);
                        \path[->] (3) edge node {a}   (6);

                        \path[->] (4) edge node {a}   (2);
                        \path[->] (4) edge node {b}   (5);
                        \path[->] (5) edge node {b}   (2);
                        \path[->] ({5}) edge node {a}   (6);
                        \path[->] ({6}) edge node {b}   (5);
                        \path[->] ({6}) edge node {b}   (2);

                        \path[->] (7) edge node {b}   (5);
                        \path[->] (7) edge node {a}   (6);

                        \path[->] (8) edge node {a}   (6);
                        \path[->] (8) edge node {b}   (5);
                    \end{tikzpicture}
                \end{center}

                Si on supprime les états qui ne peuvent être atteints, on obtient l'AFD suivant:

                \begin{tikzpicture}[>=Stealth, shorten >=1pt, auto, node distance=3cm, initial text = Début]
                    \node[initial, state](A){$\{1\}$};
                    \node[state](B)[above right=of A]{$\varnothing$};
                    \node[state, accepting](C)[below of=B]{$\{2, 3\}$};
                    \node[state](D)[right of=C]{$\{1, 2\}$};

                    \path[->] (A) edge node {a}   (B);
                    \path[->] (B) edge [loop above] node {a, b}   (B);
                    \path[->] (A) edge node {b}  (C);
                    \path[->] (C) edge [bend right] node {a}   (D);
                    \path[->] (C) edge node {b}   (B);
                    \path[->] (D) edge [bend right] node {b}   (C);
                    \path[->] (D) edge node {a}   (B);
                \end{tikzpicture}

                Le langage que cet automate accepte est le suivant:\\

                \begin{center}
                    $\{b(ab)^n$ : $n \in \mathbb{N} \, \}$
                \end{center}
            \end{continuance}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want breakable boxes, have a look at the `tcolorbox` package